# Method erasure: why is it said that the the derived class method hides the base class, but it works the other way around?

Tags: c#, oop, member-hiding

```
class Animal
{
    public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Animal::Foo()"); }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Cat::Foo()"); }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a;

        a = new Cat();
        a.Foo();  // output --> "Animal::Foo()"
    }
}
```

The compiler warning says:

> Cat.Foo hides the inherited member

However the output actually is from the base class. So to me it seems the other way around, the one I called is hidden by the one in the base class.

Comment: Because it isn't *overriding* `Animal.Foo()`, it's only *hiding* it. `Animal.Foo` is still accessible if you cast the `Cat` instance to `Animal`, as the code does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, that's a better explanation then the one in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your program is the `Animal` class implementation of `Foo` since the type of the reference is `Animal` and not `Cat`.

If the reference was of type `Cat`, the output would be `"Cat::Foo()"`.

The `Foo` method of the `Cat` class is hiding the `Foo` method of the `Animal` class because base classes can not and should not be aware of their derived classes, while derived classes are and must be aware of their base classes.

To deliberately hide a member of the base class, use the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier. This will tell the compiler that the hiding is deliberate, and will suppress the warning.

Comment: Well but that is what I do not get - if the Foo of the Cat is hiding the one of the Animal class, I would not expect that this "hidden" method is called, which is the case. I mean - it says it is hidden but still called.

Comment: See Panagiotis Kanavos's comment on the question - that's a better explanation of "why" then mine.

Comment: What's happening is that your code, since it doesn't declare `Animal.Foo` as virtual (and `Cat.Foo` as overriding `Animal.Foo`), ends up with an implicit `new` on the declaration of `Cat.Foo`.  The `new` keyword would hide `Animal.Foo` from `Cat` objects explicitly.  But, since it's happening implicitly, you are getting a warning.  Since `a` is typed as an `Animal` you get `Animal.Foo`.  If you called it as (`(Cat)a.Foo`), you'd get `Cat.Foo`.  If you want hiding, use `new`; if you want virtual/overriding behavior, using `virtual` and `override`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in that way then the method should be `Overrided` in the derived class. Check [Virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) and also [Override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

[This](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/csharp/understanding-virtual-override-and-new-keyword-in-csharp) might help you.

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Animal::Foo()"); }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Cat::Foo()"); }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a;

        a = new Cat();
        a.Foo();  // output --> "Cat::Foo()"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the reference `a` is of type Animal. When you use a reference of type Animal then the compiler assumes you want to get Animal behaviour. Overwriting virtual methods works just fine, but if you actually hide a method, then you have to explicitly use a reference of the hiding class type to reach the hiding method.

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Animal a = c; // note: a and c refer to the same object

a.Foo(); // output --> "Animal::Foo()"
c.Foo(); // output --> "Cat::Foo()"
```

As you can see from the example, when hiding is involved, the result depends on the reference type, not the object type.

Answer (score -1):

This is `polymorphism` that means the ability to redefine methods for derived classes. you must mark `Foo()` as virtual in base class and  `override` it in sub class like this:

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Animal::Foo()"); }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Cat::Foo()"); }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a;

        a = new Cat();
        a.Foo();  // output --> "Cat::Foo()"
    }
}
```

In this case the `Foo()` has polymorphic behavior!